# Why does konvas [object].position() work differently for a shape and a stage?

Tags: javascript, 2d, konvajs

When trying to position a shape in Konva you can use the `.position()` function and you use coordinates like in most 2d graphics stuff an inverted y grid so 100, 100 would be right 100px and down 100px.

BUT! when using `.position()` on the stage object you seem to get very strange effects where you (unlike any grid i've ever encountered) get an inverted x grid so that 100, 100 would be left 100px and up 100px

I haven't worked that much with 2d graphics so i might be missing something obvious but the documentation for `stage.position()` says `get/set node position relative to parent` and that it's inherited from  `Konva.Node#position` Exactly the same as is said on `shape.position()` documentation. Is it that stage doesn't have a parent so it behaves differently? Or am i missing something else?

Example that shows how the positioning works on stage vs shape
https://jsfiddle.net/uvp3k6wy/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They work exactly the same.

The `node.position()` will define "where we need to draw a node".

`stage.position({x: 50, y: 50});` means that all nodes that stage has will be drawn from `{x: 50, y: 50}` position on canvas. So whole stage is moved by `50, 50` px to right-bottom direction.

If you have a red circle in `{x: 0, y: 0}`, it will have an absolute position `{x: 50, y: 50}` because it is moved my stage position.